# Sustituir el rango [á-źÁ-Ź] con preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un string al que tengo que remplazar todos los acentos por `_`. Para eso uso `preg_replace`, pero la sustitución resulta con dos `_`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$str = "Pérez";
$str = preg_replace('/[á-źÁ-Ź]/', '_', $str);
echo $str; // P__rez
```

¿Por qué ocurre eso?

---

Como alternativa, opté por lo más práctico:

```
$str = "Pérez";
$input = ['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú', 'ä', 'ë', 'ï', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ë', 'Ï', 'Ö', 'Ü', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ā', 'ă', 'ą', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ā', 'Ă', 'Ą', 'è', 'é', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ē', 'ĕ', 'ė', 'ę', 'ě', 'Ē', 'Ĕ', 'Ė', 'Ę', 'Ě', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ì', 'ĩ', 'ī', 'ĭ', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ì', 'Ĩ', 'Ī', 'Ĭ', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ō', 'ŏ', 'ő', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ō', 'Ŏ', 'Ő', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ũ', 'ū', 'ŭ', 'ů', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ũ', 'Ū', 'Ŭ', 'Ů'];
$output = '_';
$str = str_replace($input, $output, $str);

echo $str; //P_rez
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se están conjugando 2 errores:

**1. Un regex se interpreta como bytes si no se usa el modificador `/u`**

Para poder pasar un string unicode como expresión regular, deberías haber utilizado el [modificador **u** (*PCRE_UTF8*)](http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

```
/regex/u
```

Como no lo estás usando, en realidad tu expresión se está interpretando como si fuese:

```
/[Ã¡-ÅºÃü-Å¹]/
```

- Es decir, coincide con los caracteres `Ã`, `º`, `Ã` o `¹`, o con los caracteres en los rangos `¡-Å` o `ü-Å`.
- Y lo mismo pasa con el string con el que comparaste, que es analizada como si fuese  `PÃ©rez`, y por eso encuentra 2 caracteres para reemplazar.

---

**2. El rango que usaste no está bien**

No sé de dónde sacaste la idea de usar `[á-źÁ-Ź]`, pero está mal. Para especificar un **rango** dentro de una [clase de caracteres](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.character-classes.php), hay que seguir el orden de cada caracter, que para estos rangos **no está ordenado alfabéticamente** un caracter con acento tras otro.

Veamos la tabla con lo que coincide el rango `/[á-źÁ-Ź]/u`:

[image: Latin 1 Supplement + Latin 1 Extended A]

Como se ve, en realidad es lo mismo que `/[Á-ź]/u`, pero cubre caracteres que no estás queriendo reemplazar, y deja afuera a otros.

---

#### Solución:

Quizás te conviene reemplazar todo lo que no sea una letra de la a `a` la `z`:

```
$str = "Pérez";
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/iu', '_', $str);
echo $str;
// => P_rez
```

O simplemente convertir todos los diacríticos en su letra base:

```
$str = "Pérez";
$str = iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT",$str);
echo $str;
// => Perez
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltaba indicar porque caracter vas a reemplazar lo que encuentras con la expresión regular.

Puedes hacerlo así.

```
$str = "Pérez";
$input = ['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú', 'ä', 'ë', 'ï', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ë', 'Ï', 'Ö', 'Ü', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ā', 'ă', 'ą', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ā', 'Ă', 'Ą', 'è', 'é', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ē', 'ĕ', 'ė', 'ę', 'ě', 'Ē', 'Ĕ', 'Ė', 'Ę', 'Ě', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ì', 'ĩ', 'ī', 'ĭ', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ì', 'Ĩ', 'Ī', 'Ĭ', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ō', 'ŏ', 'ő', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ō', 'Ŏ', 'Ő', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ũ', 'ū', 'ŭ', 'ů', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ũ', 'Ū', 'Ŭ', 'Ů'];
$output = '_';
$str = str_replace($input, $output, $str);

echo $str; //P_rez
```

Comment: Ya había intentado algo parecido, esto quita el acento, lo que quiero sustituirlo por _

Comment: Sólo cambia el array output por _ y listo.

Comment: Cierto, será lo más practico, pero menos elegante

Comment: O dejalo sin ese array tan largo. Solo con una cadena para que reemplace todo.

Comment: Gracias, pero aun me quedó la duda de porqué se sustituye por dos __ en  $str = preg_replace('/[á-źÁ-Ź]/', '_', $str);

Comment: Exente! con ese se cambio funciona!

Comment: Sin embargo el detalle es que con dos letras acentuadas consecutivas las sustituye por un solo _ en vez de dos __, pero en la practica en el español que yo sepa no hay una palabra que tenga dos letras acentuadas contiguas

Comment: La expresión `/[á-źÁ-Ź]+/` está mal y no debería usarse. Logra reemplazar en este caso puntual, pero es más bien fortuito... Fijate la respuesta que publiqué.