# ¿Cómo dividir una cadena?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo la siguiente cadena:

```
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
```

Cómo puedo dividirla eliminando los espacios en blanco, comas y punto, de tal forma que me dé de resultado:

```
["JavaScript", "is", "used", "in", "billions", "of", "Web", "pages", "to", "add", "functionality", "validate", "forms", "communicate", "with", "the", "server", "and", "much", "more", "JavaScript", "is", "easy", "to", "learn", "You", "will", "enjoy", "it"]
```

Comment: Podría ser con Regex `str.split(/[ .,]+/)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una opción sería emplear una expresión regular como parámetro al método [`split(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), pásandole un grupo de caracteres *[]* con los cuales coincidirá para esta ocasión *(espacio , punto , coma)* `/[ .,]/`

esta expresión provocará espacios en blanco en el array según su cadena entonces podría usar el carácter especial **+** para que tome en cuenta 1 o más coincidencias

```js
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
var newstr = str.split(/[., ]+/);
console.log(newstr);
```

Pero esto aún generará un elemento adicional vacío en el array, podría aplicar `filter` para eliminarlo , claro que este es un paso adicional , podría realizarlo de múltiples formas.

```js
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
let newstr = str.split(/[., ]+/).filter(String);
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Eliminamos todos los caracteres que no necesitamos(punto, comas) con la expresion regular `cadena.replace(/[\. ,]+/g, " ");`

2) Mediante los espacios podemos dividir con la funcion `split(" ")` obteniendo un array

```js
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";

function remove(cadena) {
  return cadena.replace(/[\. ,]+/g, " ");
}


let res = remove(str);
res = res.split(" ");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @KacosPro por casos como ... este ;-)

Comment: @Mariano pero en este caso `replace(/[\. ,]+/g, " ")` no estamos sustituyendo un espacio con otro espacio?

Comment: @KacosPro sí, pero de lo contrario eliminarías los puntos suspensivos y te quedarías con 2 espacios consecutivos, generando un elemento vacío en el split... Si realmente te interesa evitarlo: `/\s*[.,]+(?:\s[.,]*)*/g`

Comment: Con todo respeto @Mariano, eres un maldito genio del regex jaja. En todo caso mi punto iba a que sería mejor utilizar `replace(/[\.,]+/g, "")` si queremos eliminar lo que no necesitamos... o no? Hablando especificamente de la respuesta

Comment: @KacosPro en teoría... En la práctica te falla con `un,usuario que ... no respete,la puntuación`.. pero está muy bien lo que estás diciendo, es correcto

Comment: Ya debes estar acostumbrado, pero ahí va: Tienes razón @Mariano. Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Esto también podría servir, si quieres dividir la cadena en *palabras*, independientemente de cualquier símbolo.

```js
var str = ",,, JavaScript... is / used in ,,, billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. --- You will enjoy it.";

var byWords=str.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(byWords);
```

Comment: Sirve para el texto en inglés, pero fallaría con diacríticos por ejemplo

Comment: @Mariano eso he visto. ¿Alguna manera simple de hacer que funcione con diacríticos también?

Comment: en JavaScript no, la única forma es listar uno por uno. Por ejemplo, para español: `/[\wáéíóúüñ]+/gi`. La alternativa es usar la librería xregexp que implementa clases y scripts Unicode

Comment: @Mariano, esta acepta todos los acentos: `str.match(/[\A-zÀ-ú]+/gi)`

Comment: Qué horror!!! Por favor no lo uses. Respondí a algo similar en [Sustituir el rango \[á-źÁ-Ź\] con preg_replace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143984/127).